# Getting error while creating production build 'does not contain a default export'

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, react-scripts

Hii I am working with language translation using `"react-intl": "^4.1.1",` but when I creating production build then code is not compiled and shows the error about default export

Error :

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/lang/entries/es_ES.js
Attempted import error: '../locales/es_ES' does not contain a default export (imported as 'enMessages').
```

I am importing file like this:

```
import enMessages from '../locales/en_US';
```

Exporting :

```
export default {
   "sidebar.dashboard" : "Dashboard"
}
```

The most important thing is its working on the local and generating issues while creating a production build and I am using `"react-scripts": "^3.3.0"` in this project. How can I solve this?

**Update:**
After import enMessages

```
import endata from '@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/dist/locale-data/en';
import enMessages from '../locales/en_US';

const EnLang = {
   messages: {
      ...enMessages
   },
   locale: 'en-US',
   data: endata
};
export default EnLang;
```

Comment: Could you kindly show us how this file `./src/lang/entries/es_ES.js` is actually making the `export`? It might be a good starting point to troubleshoot this error.

Comment: @MwamiTovi see I have already mentioned in qustion after exporting title.

Comment: Had missed that! Thanks...

Comment: Since we are handling translation, try this `export default { sidebar: { dashboard: "Dashboard" }}. See my updated answer for better syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Have you tried a named export?

```js
/** ./src/lang/entries/es_ES.js */
import { enMessages } from '../locales/en_US

/** ./src/lang/locales/en_US.js */
export const enMessages = { "sidebar.dashboard" : "Dashboard" }
```

Default exports are [generally a bad idea](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2019/01/stop-using-default-exports-javascript-module/)... and ambiguous. What's to stop someone importing like this?

```js
import esMessages from '../locales/en_US
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but it shows the same issue with named export.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this...

```js
// ./src/lang/locales/en_US.js
export default {
   // We are trying to export a `key`, initiated as a String
-  "sidebar.dashboard" : "Dashboard",

   // let's treat sidebar/dashboard as plain keys
+  sidebar: {
+     dashboard: "Dashboard"
+  }
}
```

And consider using as follows...

```js
// ./src/lang/entries/es_ES.js
import enMessages from '../locales/en_US';

// Based on how you are using `enMessages`
+ export default { // best to use this to avoid `conflict` in later use
+  ...enMessages,  // destructure directly here
   locale: 'en-US',
   data: endata
};

// Use this for reference (though )
<Component id="sidebar.dashboard" />
```

Comment: `./src/lang/locales/en_US.js
  Line 2:11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  1 | export default {
> 2 |    sidebar.dashboard : "Dashboard"
    |           ^
  3 | }`
It generates errors

Comment: This is good progress, at least now it means the `export/import` is a success but what we now have a `parsing error`. Can you share exactly how you are using `enMessages` after being imported?

Comment: Ok, so based on this `parsing error`, we need to look into this part `sidebar.dashboard` because compilation is failing there. Could you kindly share more about `sidebar`? I think, we might have to do something like this `export default { sidebar.dashboard as Dashboard }`.

Comment: `"sidebar.dashboard" : "Dashboard"`  it just a key pair value of object ..nothing else. and `export default { sidebar.dashboard as Dashboard }` this is not working.

Comment: Definitely, we are dealing with a key/value pair but clearly something isn't working. Kindly let me know - what the aim of `export/import` a key/value pair of strings in this situation. Probably then `Dashboard` is a function, right?

Comment: No!! dashboard is not a function it is a just string I am using these stings for language translation. you just read is https://levelup.gitconnected.com/localizing-your-react-redux-application-with-react-intl-2c4fb60311e1 article.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209927/discussion-between-mwamitovi-and-varinder-sohal).